# How do I solve CS0120 in my program (An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property)?

Tags: c#

I've been needing to convert my driver to bytes, so I can load it without downloading anything.

Here is what I've tried.

```
class Program
{
    public byte[] StreamFile(string filename)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        // Create a byte array of file stream length
        byte[] ImageData = new byte[fs.Length];

        //Read block of bytes from stream into the byte array
        fs.Read(ImageData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

        //Close the File Stream
        fs.Close();
        return ImageData; //return the byte data

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamFile(@"");
    }
}
```

I get an error in my `Main`,

> An object is required for the non-static void field, method, or property "Program.StreamFile(string)"

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Yes - you're trying to call an instance method (`StreamFile`) but you don't have an instance to call it on. Either make `StreamFile` static, or create an instance of `Program` to call the method on. I'd also advise you to use a `using` statement to close the file stream automatically even if the code throws an exception, and to read up on .NET naming conventions (e.g. `imageData` for your local variable instead of `ImageData`.)

Comment: Also note that the title of your question really isn't related to the error message you're seeing. The problem is calling the method - not the implementation of the method, or what you're trying to achieve within the method. It's important to learn how to diagnose what aspect of the code is causing a problem. It's a skill which takes time, but it's worth looking back after each issue and thinking about how you could have broken it down more.

Comment: Finally, note that `File.ReadAllBytes` already exists, so you don't need your `StreamFile` method at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides it is not clear to me what you would like to achieve, your code does not compile because you need `StreamFile` to be static, since you are calling it from a static method.
So this fixes the syntax error

```cs
class Program
{
    //     !!!!!! add this
    public static byte[] StreamFile(string filename)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

        // Create a byte array of file stream length
        byte[] ImageData = new byte[fs.Length];

        //Read block of bytes from stream into the byte array
        fs.Read(ImageData, 0, System.Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);

        //Close the File Stream
        fs.Close();
        return ImageData; //return the byte data

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamFile(@"");
    }
}
```

You can rewrite your code and make it more robust in this way (.net core)

```cs
class Program
{
    public static byte[] StreamFile(string filename)
    {
        return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamFile(@"");
    }
}
```

**EDITED** the below code shows how to use `using`, but requires little more knowledge about how to handle the buffers (I just placed an exception as this is out of scope now)

```cs
class Program
{
    public static byte[] StreamFile(string filename)
    {
        byte[] data;
        // let the stream be managed on its own
        using (var fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            // If you want to ask for the length of the file, be sure nobody is changing it over time. See the FileShare.Read above

            data = new byte[fs.Length];

            if (data.Length != fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length))
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Something went wrong.");
        }
        return data;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamFile(@"");
    }
}
```

Please note that the `using` construct automatically closes/disposes the resource you are using when it goes out of scope<sup>1</sup>. This way you cannot make mistakes and it is clear what is your intent.

You must lock the file (in your case, just asking nobody can change it via `FileShare.Read`) otherwise you may have a race condition on the file since you might read an inconsistent data.

---

<sup>1</sup> They must implement the `IDisposable` interface.

Comment: Note that this is calling `Stream.Read` and ignoring the return value, which is generally a bad idea. I'd get rid of `StreamFile` entirely and just call `File.ReadAllBytes`...

Answer (score 0):

the error you get is because of calling a non static method from inside of the static main method, 
may be you should change your question title.

add static keyword to StreamFile method.